# How do I reconfigure PHP to enable Thread Safety on my Lamp Server

Tags: php, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads

I'm interested in using pthreads for my PHP application. Only problem is whenever I try to install it on my server using `pecl install pthreads` it tells me my PHP isn't configured using ZTS. Now I started googeling a bit and found out you need to recompile it with the source code. My problem is, I'm using LAMP and I don't want my whole setup to destroy itself but I'd really love to use Pthreads. Could somebody tell me how to still enable thread safety in a way that doesn't scr*w up my server?

My server is running Ubuntu 12.04. Apache2, MySQL and PHP 5.5.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be binary distributions around providing a `libphp5-zts.so` module to be used by Apache instead of the standard `libphp5.so` which provides the `NTS` API. However question on how to configure and setup systems is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I tried searching for the lib but I can't find it. Could you link me to it? I just want it to work, I don't have to reconfigure, I just thought it was the only way.